# path finding: calculating the optimal path, where "optimal" means maximum distance within a given time

Tags: combinatorics

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here's my problem:

I have a large set of points, where each point represents a coordinate. I need to develop an algorithm that calculates which points to visit in order to maximise the total distance travelled within a certain time span (e.g., 24 hours). For each path between two points I know the distance and the maximum speed.

In addition, there's a constraint. Each path can only be travelled twice (so, up and down is possible but then both points cannot be used again).

My problem is: I don't know where to start. I've looked at some pathfinding algorithms (eg Dijkstra's), but they're all to find the least distance whereas I need to find the maximum distance!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of a specific algorithm for such problems. My only thought would be to approximate a solution with simulated annealing, starting from a path (closed?) and making local modifications that increase the total distance travelled within the time constraint (roughly trying to maintain the maximum average speed).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following approach should get you somewhere: (It resembles Kruskal's algorithm)

1. For every edge, calculate the speed.
2. Order the edges by speed.
3. Keep adding the fastest edge to the graph.
4. When the total time of all edges added reaches half of the limit, $\frac T2$, stop.
5. If the resulting graph is connected, this is the best you can get. Since you may travel over each edge twice, it is easy to visit all edges twice. Just start somewhere and walk like a 'deep-search' pattern, i.e. go further over unvisited edges when you can, and go back otherwise.
   If there is an edge (are edges) connected to your graph that can be still be visited within the time restriction, start there.
6. If the resulting graph is not connected, continue adding edges until one of the components has a total time of $\frac T2$. This may not be optimal when it is better to go from one component to the other over a small inefficient edge, but I don't have a solution to that.